# How to get an element of a JSON object in bash?

Tags: json, bash, curl

I'm performing a curl command using a bash file and the return is a json object. How to get a element of this json object in this bash file?

Put request

https://sms.world-text.com/v2.0/sms/send?id=11111&key=Testkey&srcaddr=DA_Health&dstaddr=000000000000&method=PUT&txt=Message_Text_Text

Response

{"status":"1","error":"1000","desc":"Authorisation Failure"}

to="000000000000"
message="Test_message"
url="https://sms.world-text.com/v2.0/sms/send?id=11111&key=TestKey&srcaddr=SMSMsg&dstaddr=${to}&method=PUT&txt=${message}"

return=$(curl -sm 5 $url --data-urlencode "${message}" -A 'Test')

Finally, the "return" variable has the value below:
{"status":"1","error":"1000","desc":"Authorisation Failure"}

I expect to perform that validation

if [[ "$status" != 0]]; then

> &2 echo "$return"
>   fi

But how can I get the element "status" and his value "1" from $return in the bash file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sed` to filter out the status code from the $result.

```
status=$(echo "$return" | sed -E 's/\{"status"\s?:\s?"([0-9]+)".*/\1/')
```

and then can do test:

```
if [[ "$status" != 0]]; then
   >&2 echo "$return"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

it's ideologically wrong to process JSON format with JSON-agnostic tools (like awk, sed, etc). JSON format must be processed with JSON-aware tools.

E.g., if your curl response was a multi-line JSON (which is quite often the case), then most likely the `sed` based solution would not work right for you.

One of the unix utilities to work with JSON is  **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)**, with that one your solution would look like this:

```
status=$(<<<$return jtc -w[status] -qq)
```

and then you can apply your check:

```
if [[ "$status" != 0]]; then
   >&2 echo "$return"
fi
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)** - shell cli tool for JSON operations

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq`. Here is a comprehensive guide about the tool -> https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/.

e.g.

```
echo '{ "foo": 123, "bar": 456 }' | jq '.foo'
```

This would print 123.

It also works with nested objects.